# Using cometD in a tapestry web page

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tapestry, cometd

When i put this code in my tapestry page and click on some buttons already created in the same page, the page reloads(open picture bellow ) :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTxUQ.jpg)
therefore the message1.message doesnt show up.
Can you help ?

Answer (score 1):

The picture only shows some code ?

Clicking on some button should not reload the whole page, it's 2015 and reloading the whole page is so 1990 :)

I guess you can mitigate by using the [CometD reload extension](http://docs.cometd.org/3/reference/#_extensions_reload), but the real solution would be to avoid that the whole page is reloaded when you click that button.

Comment: The page refreshes just when i put this code in my tml page <t:cometd.PushTarget topic="/myChannel" event="receive" update="replace"/>. 

this is my nSubmitFromFormMessage,

  Block onSubmitFromMessageForm() {
      
      sZone=true;
      MessageSend messageSend = new MessageSend();
      messageSend.setGroup(selectedGroup);
      messageSend.setMessage(message);
         pushManager.broadcast("/myChannel", messageSend);
         return messageZone.getBody();
     }

Comment: and this is my onreceive function
    Block onReceive(MessageSend inMessage) {
      sZone=true;
         String group = inMessage.getGroup();
         System.out.println("Group = " + group);    
         System.out.println("onReceived Block");
        this.message1 = inMessage;
      return messageZone.getBody();
     }

Comment: The page reload is a Tapestry mechanism, not CometD's. I don't know how to help you in this case... perhaps there is a Tapestry mechanism to avoid the page reload ?